# Find an equation of the plane which passes through…

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative

Help me find an equation of the plane which passes through the point A(1,−2,−1) and which is tangent to the surface z=ln(2x+y).

The normal vector is:
$$
[\frac{2}{2x+y},\frac{1}{2x+y}, -1]
$$
A is not a tangent point (I checked it once I started solving this). 
How to find a tangent point? If I found it, I'd be able to find the equation of the plane.

Regards.

Comment: Not enough info to find *the* tangent plane -- there are infinitely many containing your point $A$.

Answer (score 1):

The equation of a plane can be written as the set of all points $\textbf {r}$ such that $\textbf {n.r} = \textbf {n.a}$ where $\textbf {n}$ is a normal vector to the plane and $\textbf {a}$ is a point on the plane.

Since A and the point on your surface that the plane is tangent to (call this point B) are both on the plane, the vector joining A to B must be perpendicular to the normal vector to the surface at B (so their dot product must be zero). Solving this should give you the set of points on the surface for which the tangent plane contains A.

Answer (score 0):

The peculiar feature of this function, $ \ z \ = \ \ln(2x + y) \ $ , is that not only are its "level curves" the straight lines $ \ 2x \ + \ y \ = \ c \ $ , but the logarithmic function composed on a linear function yields partial derivatives such that all of the points on each level curve *share* the same normal vector.  Each level curve then lies in a particular tangent plane.

The domain of this function is $ \ 2x \ + \ y \ > \ 0 \ $ , so the point $ \ ( 1, \ -2, \ -1 ) \ $ is "external" to the function surface and sits "out over the abyss", so to speak.  The characteristics of our function make it quite convenient to determine the tangent plane that contains this point.  Since we can choose *any* point on a level curve to find the tangent plane to the surface, we will use $ \ ( 0, \ c, \ \ln c ) \ $ .  The generic normal vector is as you have already found, so the tangent plane to our chosen level curve is

$$ z \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{c} \ (x \ - \ 0) \ + \ \frac{1}{c} \ (y \ - \ c) \ + \ \ln c \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{c} \ x \ + \ \frac{1}{c} \ (y \ - \ c) \ + \ \ln c\ \ . $$

We may now determine what value of $ \ c \ $ , if any, provides a tangent plane through the given external point:

$$ -1 \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{c} \ \cdot \ 1 \ + \ \frac{1}{c} \ ([-2] \ - \ c) \ + \ \ln c \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ -1 \ \ = \ \ \frac{2}{c} \ - \ \frac{2}{c} \ - \ 1 \ + \ \ln c $$

$$ \Rightarrow \ \ 0  \ = \  \ln c \ \ \Rightarrow \ \  c \ = \ 1 \ \ .  $$

The tangent plane in question then is  $  \ z \ = \ 2x \ + \ ( y - 1 ) \ +  \ 0 \ $  or $ \ 2x \ + \ y \ - \ z \ = \ 1 \ $ (with the tangent points on the surface being $ \ ( x_0 \ , \ 1 \ - \ 2 \ x_0 \ , \ 0 ) \ $ .  The graph below presents a view of the geometrical arrangement.

[image]

*The view looks "up from below" at the function surface (in green) and the tangent plane (in red); the lines meeting at the tangent plane are used to mark the external point* ( 1, -2, -1 ) .